# bootstrap Dropdown multipleselect Onchange is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Multiple Select Drop down which has options 
retrieved dynamically from Database as

```
<select size="3" name="p" id="p" class="dis_tab" multiple>
<?php
echo "<option>". $row['abc'] ."</option>";
//Option value fetching from Database
?>
</select>
```

Activated Dropdown as

```
$("#p").multipleSelect();
```

On Page load the dropdown values will be all Checked as

```
$("#p").multipleSelect("checkAll");
```

On change of checkbox values I need to get checked values

I tried onchange but its not working

```
 $('#p').change(function() {
        alert('test');
});
```

Is there anyone to help me out?

Comment: Assuming I've googled the right library, use the `onChange` property of the initialisation object: http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange

Comment: I'm using "multipleSelect" anyhow thank you for "multiselect" library link :-)

Comment: A link to that library would help us to diagnose the issue then

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#p').on('change',function() {
    alert('test');
 });
```

use this

Answer (score -1):

As Rory McCrossan, I am not sure that I googled the right library.
Is it this : [Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown](https://codepen.io/craigwheeler/pen/OOMMVo) ?

If yes, then, I have been abble to get the values by targetting the select box with the ID

```
    $('#myId').change(function(e){
        console.log($(this).val()); // look at you your conseole :)
    });
```

Assuming that you have `<select id="myId"...>`